# Best way to generate large Zip File in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am generating Zip File in background process (sidekiq) by **downloading** pictures from S3 url and then **uploading** & sending the download ZIP link via email. Production **EC2 instance has 16GB RAM**. It succeeds for 10 GB album and shows buff/cache (10GB) but **will the same process crash for album size greater than 50GB?** If so, what is the best way to get it working.

Below is the working code. Need some suggestions. Thanks!!

```
  def self.generate_zip(album_id, user_id)
    album = Album.find(album_id)
    pictures = album.album_pictures 

    temp_dir = Rails.root.to_s + "/tmp/"
    zip_path = File.open(temp_dir + "Album_#{album.name}_#{Date.today.to_s}.zip", "wb")


    zip_stream = Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer(zip_path) do |zip|
      index = 0
      pictures.each do |photo|
          index += 1
          zip.put_next_entry(index.to_s + "_" + photo.image_file_name)
          data = open(photo.image_url)
          IO.copy_stream(data, zip)  
      end
    end
    zip_stream.fsync # flush any buffered data to disk
    zip_stream.rewind

    #Upload the ZIP to S3
    user = User.find(user_id)
    export = user.exports.build
    export.item_id = object.id
    export.item_type = object.class.name 
    export.archive = File.open(zip_path) 
    export.save! 
    export
  ensure
    FileUtils.rm zip_path if File.exists?(zip_path)
  end
```

Comment: I would recommend to use external archiver for that purposes, it's not very efficient to use ruby for archiving large amounts of data...